# rfftw2d_create_plan implementation in c++

Tags: c++, fftw

I am trying to perform FFT using the FFTW lib available for c++. Since there are many options for FFTW available i am trying to implement fft using the rfftwnd method(since my data is real).

```
 #include<rfftw.h>
{
fftw_real a[width][2*(height/2+1)],b[width][2*(height/2+1)],c[width][height];
fftw_complex *A,*B,C[width][height/2+1];

rfftwnd_plan rp,rpin;
fftw_real scale = 1.0/(width*height);

const int H = height;
const int W= width;
rp = rfftw2d_create_plan(W,H,FFTW_REAL_TO_COMPLEX,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
rpin = rfftw2d_create_plan(width, height, FFTW_COMPLEX_TO_REAL,FFTW_ESTIMATE);

A = (fftw_complex*) &a[0][0];
B = (fftw_complex*) &b[0][0];
for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<height;j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = la(i,j);
    }
}
 }
```

So i am basically trying to implement the fft on an image for this i need to create the plans as suggested in the FFTW documentation.
But when i do this i get an errror saying

```
 error: undefined reference to `rfftw2d_create_plan'
```

could someone please help as to why this is happening? Am i missing something here?

Comment: If this is new development, you might want to consider starting with FFTW 3 since FFTW 2 has been marked as obsolete (see [FFTW's download page](http://www.fftw.org/download.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a linker error which tells you that the linker cannot find the indicated function, with the most likely reason being that the linker doesn't know about the `librfftw.a` library which contains the definition (see [this question & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/2994596) for more details, and more specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/2994596)).

According to [this section of FFTW documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_3.html#SEC34):

> Programs using RFFTWND should be linked with -lrfftw -lfftw -lm on Unix systems, or with the FFTW, RFFTW, and standard math libraries in general.

So, you should be adding those required flags for compilation.